# floating type names matching integer type names?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, types

I have to say I was pleased when I opened up c# to see the integer data types being `Int16,Int32 and Int64`. It removed any ambiguity e.g int increasing in size with age.

What surprises me is why there isn't or doesn't seem to be `Float16,Float32 and Float64`
or atleast not in normal use: a quick search of MSDN refers to float64 as R8 (unmanaged type) isn't this the same as a double

My guess would be there isn't as much ambiguity in Single and Double (or even Extended(Float80) which doesn't exist in c# as far as I know, I'm not sure how this could be marshalled for that matter.) Although Decimal seems to be a Float128 and I've noted it refered to as "Extended Floating Point Precision", Should we see an Int128 to match it?
**EDIT:** There isn't any ambiguity at all in Single or Double (which was a guess but it appears to be true and I thought I'd add this for clarity.)

Should we expect to see this kind of naming convention?/ would you appreciate it if we did?

Or should we go one step further and have `Int<N>` for arbitary number sizes? (yes I realise there are libraries out there which support this kind of thing)

Comment: Given this is a poll-style question, perhaps it should be community wiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are various different things to consider here:

- The types exposed by .NET

  - What's available
  - What each type is called
- What ends up being aliased by other languages, e.g. C# using `int` to mean `System.Int32`

Personally I would have preferred `Float32` and `Float64` as the CLR types. I can certainly see some confusion in F# naming the types "float" (for `System.Double`) and "float32" (for `System.Single`). I wouldn't want `Decimal` to be called `Float128`; possibly `Decimal128` to allow for other similar types though.

Note that `Byte` isn't `UInt8` by the way - presumably because bytes are usually used for arbitrary binary storage rather than for genuinely numberic quantities.

I don't think there's very much reason to have arbitrary values for `Int<N>` though. At least, I suspect the usage is sufficiently specialised to relegate it to a custom class library rather than making it part of the framework. (Note, however, that `BigInteger` is part of .NET 4.0.)

Comment: +1 because this is a poll-style question and I would also have preferred Float32/Float64... very slightly. There's something to be said for ada-style ranged integers as an even further step to `Int<N>`, but eiffel-style contracts seem to cover those kinds of situations better in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's float and double in C#, instead of single and double, but it's the same general difference.  Keep in mind there's an [alias in C# for every built-in type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx).  As for the arbitrary number sizes, F# is introducing BigInteger, which should take care of that, but the arbitrary size while specifying the number of rationals the integer can hold would most likely be a performance hit, as the built-in types are all finely tuned to performance in the CLR.

Also, decimal isn't a floating point type in the IEEE sense.  Sure, it's a high precision type that allows for a floating decimal point, but it's not a "floating point type" in the IEEE sense of the word.  Other than it's limited precision, it won't do the strange things float will do (such as 2x2=3.9999999999999), and for that reason, it's frequently used in financial calculations.

If you're really looking for something that will allow you to crunch numbers heavily, you may want to look to a functional language like F# instead of C#.  Functional languages are typically better at heavy number crunching anyways... they tend to be more concise.

As for naming convention... I started on C#... C# is my standard, and so to me, other languages are weird.  It's all in the perspective the developer comes from, I suppose.